# How to pass the JSONArray from one JSP to another JSP and show the results in table?

Tags: java, jsp, arrays, json

Below is my JSP page `(abc.jsp)` from which I am calling another JSP page `jspConnection.jsp` using the jQuery and then `jspConnection.jsp` will return me back the query result to `abc.jsp` and then I need to use the result to show them in a table -

Below code I have in abc.jsp from which I am calling jspConnection.jsp -

```
$.post("jspConnection.jsp", {'id': id},
        function (data) {
            // make a new table here from JSONObject
            // and show the result here
        }
);
```

Table should look like this in abc.jsp after iterating the JSONObject -

```
FirstName           LastName                Address             Email                   PhoneNumber
SomeValue           SomeOtherValue          SomeOtherValue      SomeOtherValue          SomeOtherValue
...                 ...                     ...                 ....                    ....
...                 ...                     ...                 ....                    ....
```

Now below is the `jspConnection.jsp` from which I am returning the result of my sql query to `abc.jsp` page. My SQL query will return me multiple rows.

Below is my sql query which I am executing -

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Libs, Email, PhoneNumber from Testing;
```

Now I need to return a JSON Object of my above SELECT query -

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

while (resultSet.next()) {

// This might be wrong way to make an object for my scenario
    obj.put("FirstName", rs.getString(1)) ;
    obj.put("LastName", rs.getString(2)) ;
    obj.put("Address", rs.getString(3)) ;
    obj.put("Email", rs.getString(4)) ;
    obj.put("PhoneNumber", rs.getString(5)) ;
}
list.add(obj);

response.getWriter().write(obj.toString());
```

Now I am not sure how to return the JSONObject such that I can make the table in abc.jsp correctly.. As currently the way I am making JSONObject and JSONArray is not right I guess so not able to understand how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new `JSONObject` at the beginning of each iteration, and you must add it to your `JSONArray` at the end of each iteration. Perhaps like this,

```
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

while (resultSet.next()) {
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();       // Move this here.
  // This might be wrong way to make an object for my scenario
  obj.put("FirstName", rs.getString(1));
  obj.put("LastName", rs.getString(2));
  obj.put("Address", rs.getString(3));
  obj.put("Email", rs.getString(4));
  obj.put("PhoneNumber", rs.getString(5));
  list.add(obj);                           // And this here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Elliott for your suggestion. Any idea how to send this JSONArray to my `abc.jsp` and then generate the table accordingly?

Comment: You probably shouldn't do that. Return the JSONArray to the client, and use jQuery to render it in the browser.

Comment: Which client you are talking about here? In my scenario the client is abc.jsp which is calling jspConnection.jsp and this jspConnection.jsp runs the select query and gives the data back to abc.jsp so that the result can be shown on abc.jsp

Comment: @akiiddweeber Then why are you serializing the data to JSON? Just write the HTML is "jspConnection.jsp" so that it is rendered on "abc.jsp"

Comment: I am serializing the data bcoz I thought that is the only way to send an Object from one JSP (jspConnection.jsp) to another JSP(abc.jsp). In short I need to generate a table with all the columns and its values in `abc.jsp` page.. So that is the reason I am calling jspConnection.jsp which can give me the JSONObject which I can use to deserialize and render it in the table.. I cannot write as it is because I have one more other table in `abc.jsp` and this new table I need to render it just below my original table..

Comment: I have one more table in abc.jsp and I need to render this new table by deserializing the JSONObject just below my original table.. So that is the reason I need to pass it..

Comment: Just store the JSONArray in the request. See [ServletRequest#setAttribute(String, Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) and [Object ServletRequest#getAttribute(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45035/discussion-between-akiiddweeber-and-elliott-frisch)