# how to pass a javascript array object from a jsp page to another jsp page or servlets

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp, servlets

The Problem is - i have generated a javascript JSON array (below screenshot) in a jsp page. Now i want to send that javascript array object from the current page(JSP) to another page(JSP or servlet). Please help.
Please provide me the alternative solutions as well which will work best.

[image: JSON Array screenshot]

************ To be more precise *****************
 I am having a project which involves JSP and Servlets. Now there is index.jsp which asks a user to upload data sheet(excel sheet), the file is uploaded on the server by calling/sending the file through a servlet. That servlet then tries to extract the data(rows and columns) and generates a 2D Java array with same dimensions. This array is then sent to a JSP page (output.jsp) which gets this java array and converts it to JavaScript JSON array called as "**data**". I am performing some edit operations on this page and the changes gets affected in array accordingly. What i want is - I want to send that **data** array object to another jsp page where i can convert it into Java Array for further use.

Comment: The attached image is not in anyway helpful. Can you rephrase your question to explain exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069952/how-to-pass-the-jsonarray-from-one-jsp-to-another-jsp-and-show-the-results-in-ta    this might help

Answer (score 0):

you can probably save java script array object as a session attribute & get that in another JSP.

```
session.setAttribute("Object",object)


session.getAttribute("Object",object)
```